# MAC homebrew php pdo firebird driver

Tags: php, pdo, firebird, homebrew

I installed php53 on mac osx with homebrew. I need to enable pdo driver for firebird.
I tried to instal via pecl ..

I donwload http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_FIREBIRD 
and compile this but I get this error

```
...
...
configure: error: libgds or libib_util not found! Check config.log for more information.
```

I found that means that I don't have installed firebird develepoment libraries...

I have installed firebird 2.0 on my mac.. this version is working Flamerobin.

Does anyone have pdo firebird driver on mac server installed via homebrew?

Comment: Googling around for that error on Mac gives a lot of hints. In any case make sure you have installed the `firebird2-dev` libraries.

Comment: I found this advice, but i dont know how and what firebird2-dev library install on mac. I have installed this on my mac http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-0-7/

Comment: Sorry, can not help there. I would suggest to subscribe to the [Firebird support mailing lists](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists) and ask them

Answer (score 1):

Pdo Firebird from pecl is deprecated , i will updated it soon that i get access to it

you need to download the source code for php extract it and then build only the pdo_firebird extension

```
cd ext/pdo_firebird
phpize
./configure
```

(you might need to pass the firebird framework dir --with-pdo-firebird=/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework )

```
make
sudo make install
```

after that you need to copy the extension in your brew build php extensions folder and add it to php.ini

```
extension=pdo_firebird.so
```

I also recommend firebird 2.5.x is more recent and well supported on recent macosx versions

Comment: So i installed firebird 2.5 and this error is ok now. But when i try `make` it comes with this error `./php_pdo_firebird_int.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ibase.h' file not found
#include <ibase.h>`

Comment: For those having the same problem I was able to solve it by making a copying the files from `/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Headers/` to the `ext/pdo_firebird` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this issue by :

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Versions/A/Firebird /usr/local/lib/libfbclient.dylib
```

macOS High Siera 10.13.3